# Tool tip pointed arrow pie highchart

Tags: jquery, html, css, highcharts

[image]

[image]

Tooltip on bar having pointed arrow to down, but for pie it is showing just rectangular box.

I want same pointed arrow for pie chart also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your tooltip shape by extending Highcharts.

```
(function(Highcharts) {
      Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.callout = function(x, y, w, h, options) {
      var arrowLength = 6,
        halfDistance = 6,
        r = Math.min((options && options.r) || 0, w, h),
        safeDistance = r + halfDistance,
        anchorX = options && options.anchorX,
        anchorY = options && options.anchorY,
        path;

      path = [
        'M', x + r, y,
        'L', x + w - r, y, // top side
        'C', x + w, y, x + w, y, x + w, y + r, // top-right corner
        'L', x + w, y + h - r, // right side
        'C', x + w, y + h, x + w, y + h, x + w - r, y + h, // bottom-right corner
        'L', x + r, y + h, // bottom side
        'C', x, y + h, x, y + h, x, y + h - r, // bottom-left corner
        'L', x, y + r, // left side
        'C', x, y, x, y, x + r, y // top-right corner
      ];

      path.splice(23, 3,
        'L', w / 2 + halfDistance, y + h,
        w / 2, y + h + arrowLength,
        w / 2 - halfDistance, y + h,
        x + r, y + h
      );

      return path;
    };
  }(Highcharts));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p0vk50o6/

Docs:
- http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts